# devexpress gridcontrol set image in column when data exists

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridcontrol on the form with several columns. One of the columns has a repositoryitem (imageedit).

Whith an sql query I get the dataset from the database and assign it to the datasource of the gridcontrol. Everything is fine till this point.

In the dataset (it contains only one datatable) I have a field, which contains a string value. I would like to have the following: if this field isn't empty, then I would like to have an image in the column (imageedit), if it is empty, then no image needed.

How could I achieve this? With the ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData Event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GridView.CustomRowCellEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic). Just create an empty `RepositoryItem` and use it:

```cs
private RepositoryItem emptyItem = new RepositoryItem();

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "YourImageColumn")
    {
        object value = gridView1.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle)["YourStringColumn"];

        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            e.RepositoryItem = emptyItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but if I try to filter on this column, I get a nullreferenc exception on the line "string value=gridview1 etc. What could be the problem?